# SIGSEGV when reading a QStandardItem from a QDataStream in release mode only

Tags: qt, serialization, segmentation-fault

I have some troubles debugging this piece of code that writes a QStandardItemModel into a file using QDataStream for serialization :

"in" and "out" are QDataStream objects.

"userInfosModel" is a QStandardItemModel that represent a table.

Here is the writer function :

```
int rows = userInfosModel->rowCount();
int columns = userInfosModel->columnCount();

// writing rows and columns
out << (quint32)rows;
out << (quint32)columns;

for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    for(int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {

        QStandardItem *item = userInfosModel->item(row,col);

        if(item)
            out << *item;
        else 
            return false;            
    }

return true;
```

and the reader function where the segmentation fault occurs when col = 1 :

```
userInfosModel->clear();

quint32 rows, columns;

qDebug() << "reading user infos" << endl;

in >> rows;
in >> columns;

qDebug() << "rows  = " << rows << "cols = " << columns << endl;

for(quint32 row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    for(quint32 col = 0; col < columns ; col++) {

        // no SIGSEGV if i uncomment the line below
        // qDebug() << "row = " << row << " col = "<< col << endl;

        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem;

        if(item)
            in >> *item; // SIGSEGV in release mode only
        else
            return false;

        userInfosModel->setItem(row,col,item);  

    }
```

The whole project is linked against in-house shared libs and everything is working fine in debug mode.

I guess there is a stack corruption somewhere in the release build, probably a buffer overflow but i cannot find it so far.

What i am missing here ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll go nowhere unless you have a build of Qt configured with `force_debug_info`, *and* you add `CONFIG += force_debug_info` to your project file, and then you run the release build of your application under the debugger. That way you'll be able to debug it and figure what goes wrong.

Comment: what line would you uncomment to avoid SIGSEGV?

Comment: The line with qDebug() . I have added some comments to make it more clear in the code. Without this line, the debugger stop at `in >> *item` in release mode only